# can not import Auth from aws-amplify in Angular even though docs says I can

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplify-auth-cognito

I am developing an Angular app with AWS Cognito Authentication using Amplify Angular package. I need to override methods to get callback from signin. I installed the following packages as mentioned in the docs (from my package json):

```
"@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^5.0.12"
"aws-amplify": "^6.0.21"
```

When I try to import;
import { Amplify, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

it does not let me do it. Gives error on importing:

```
Module '"aws-amplify"' has no exported member 'Auth'
```

But in Amplfy Auth docs, there are examples of this usage. What do I miss?

these are the official docs I follow:

https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator
https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator/customization

Comment: I think that the correct syntax is : import { Amplify } from '@aws-amplify/core'; and import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Comment: I copied it directly from docs I shared above. The second link

Comment: Check v6 : https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/troubleshooting/migrate-from-javascript-v5-to-v6/#4-upgrade-category-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc references you provided appear to be for version 5. However, the latest version v6 allows you to do it shown below.

1. Add import statement.

   ```
   import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
   import { SignUpInput, SignUpOutput, signUp } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
   ```
2. Invoke `signUp` method.

   ```
   function doSignup(signUpInput: SignUpInput): Promise<SignUpOutput> {
     .
     .
     .
     return signUp(signUpInput);
   }
   ```

Also refer to this guide
[Migrate from Amplify JavaScript v5 to v6](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/troubleshooting/migrate-from-javascript-v5-to-v6/) (if required).